# how to implement sliding menu to work in android

Tags: android, slider, actionbarsherlock

i got sliding menu lib [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) & i want both left and right slide menu to come based on operation, in my case always left to right slide comes irrespective of the icon click. here is the code

where is the problem?. how to make both slide to work?

```
package com.example.simple_left_right_slider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

import com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;


public class MainActivity extends  FragmentActivity{

    private SlidingMenu menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        //menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new SampleListFragment())
          .commit();

        menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame1);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.menu_frame1, new SampleListFragment())
          .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

          case android.R.id.home:
            menu.toggle();
            break;

          case R.id.github:
            menu.toggle();
            break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are using the same `menu.toggle()` for both actions: according to [sources](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/SlidingMenu.java) that method opens/closes the left menu. You should use `showSecondaryMenu()` to open right menu instead.

Comment: Hey one more thing, i want the menu to swap left.. i mean including the title bar, how can i do.. if i do that title bar is not swapping what option i have to set?

Comment: I got it, its menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);. thanks lot